# chaining promises inreact and using responses from api calls

Tags: post, redux, react-redux, promise, action

the following code is a handle click save function supposed to save a book form which includes details of the book and a book cover. the current issue is that when I dispatch the upload image action function my is not wait for a response containing the URL of the book cover and continue to go ahead with the process continuing with the following line of code. The reason I say this is because when I check my console logs all of the console logs in the component fire and provide results before the console logs present in the action function provide a response

below is the code for the handle click function

```
``const handleEditClick = () => {
    setIsEditing(true);
  };

  const handleSaveClick = () => {
    setIsSaving(true); // Set saving state to true
  
    const editedBook = {
      ...book,
      title: editedTitle,
      author: editedAuthor,
      description: editedDescription,
    };
  
    if (selectedImage) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('bookCover', selectedImage);
  
      dispatch(uploadImage(formData))
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.payload)
          editedBook.bookCover = response.payload.fileURL;
  
          return dispatch(editBook(book._id, editedBook));
        })
        .then(() => {
          setIsEditing(false);
          setIsSaving(false);
          setError(null);
          setEditedTitle(book.title); // Reset edited values
          setEditedAuthor(book.author);
          setEditedDescription(book.description);
        })
        .catch((uploadError) => {
          console.log(uploadError);
          setIsSaving(false);
          setError('Failed to upload image. Please try again.');
        });
    } else {
      dispatch(editBook(book._id, editedBook))
        .then(() => {
          setIsEditing(false);
          setIsSaving(false);
          setError(null);
          setEditedTitle(book.title); // Reset edited values
          setEditedAuthor(book.author);
          setEditedDescription(book.description);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          setIsSaving(false);
          setError('Failed to save changes. Please try again.');
        });
    }`
  };`
```

below is the code for the route

```
router.post('/upload', bookController.uploadImage);
```

below is the code for the action

```
`import axios from 'axios';

// ADD BOOK ACTIONS

export const fetchBooksRequest = () => {
  return { type: 'FETCH_BOOKS_REQUEST' };
};

export const fetchBooksSuccess = (books) => {
  return { type: 'FETCH_BOOKS_SUCCESS', payload: books };
};

export const fetchBooksFailure = (error) => {
  return { type: 'FETCH_BOOKS_FAILURE', payload: error };
};

export const fetchBooks = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchBooksRequest());
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:5000/api/books')
      .then((response) => {
        const books = response.data;
        dispatch(fetchBooksSuccess(books));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(fetchBooksFailure(error.message));
      });
  };
};

// EDIT BOOK ACTIONS

export const editBookSuccess = (book) => {
  return { type: 'EDIT_BOOK_SUCCESS', payload: book };
}

export const editBookRequest = () => {
  return { type: 'EDIT_BOOK_REQUEST' };
};

export const editBookFailure = (error) => {
  return { type: 'EDIT_BOOK_FAILURE', payload: error };
};

export const editBook = (bookId, updatedBookData) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(editBookRequest());
    axios
      .put(`http://localhost:5000/api/books/${bookId}`, updatedBookData)
      .then((response) => {
        const editedBook = response.data;
        dispatch(editBookSuccess(editedBook));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(editBookFailure(error.message));
      });
  };
};




// UPLOAD IMAGE ACTIONS


export const uploadImageRequest = () => {
  return { type: 'UPLOAD_IMAGE_REQUEST' };
};

export const uploadImageFailure = (error) => {
  return { type: 'UPLOAD_IMAGE_FAILURE', payload: error };
};

export const uploadImageSuccess = (fileURL) => {
  return { type: 'UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS', payload: fileURL };
};



export const uploadImage = (formData) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(uploadImageRequest());
    axios
      .post(`http://localhost:5000/api/books/upload`, formData)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.fileURL)
        const fileURL = response.data.fileURL; // Assuming the response contains the file URL
        dispatch(uploadImageSuccess(fileURL));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(uploadImageFailure(error.message));
      });
  };
};


// Other book-related actions`
```

below is the component for the controller

```
const Book = require('../models/bookSchema');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');


// Retrieve all Books from the database.

const getAllBooks = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const books = await Book.find();
      res.json(books);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error: Retrivee book error' });
    }
  };


// Create and Save a new Book

const saveBook = async (req, res) => {

  // Validate request
  console.log(req.body)
  if (!req.body.title) {
    res.status(400).send({ message: "Content can not be empty!" });
    return;
  }

  // Create a new Book
  const book = new Book({
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description,
      author: req.body.author,
  });

  // Save book in the database
  book
    .save(book)
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the book."
      });
    });
};


// Upload an image file to the server
 
const uploadImage = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'No files were uploaded' });
    }

    const { bookCover } = req.files; // Assuming the field name in the form is 'bookCover'

    // Generate a unique file name to avoid conflicts
    const fileName = `${Date.now()}_${bookCover.name}`;

    const uploadPath = path.join(__dirname, '../imageUploads', fileName);

    // Move the uploaded file to the specified path
    bookCover.mv(uploadPath, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to upload the file' });
      }

      // Construct the file URL using the base URL and the encoded file name
      const encodedFileName = encodeURIComponent(fileName);
      const fileURL = `http://localhost:5000/api/imageUploads/${encodedFileName}`;
      console.log(fileURL)

      // Return the file URL to the frontend
      res.json({ fileURL: fileURL  });

    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
};


// Edit book by ID

const editBookById = async (req, res) => {
  const bookId = req.params._id;
  const updatedBook = req.body;

  try {
    // Find the book by ID and update its details
    const book = await Book.findByIdAndUpdate(bookId, updatedBook, { new: true });

    if (!book) {
      // Book with the given ID not found
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Book not found' });
    }

    // Book updated successfully
    res.json(book);
  } catch (error) {
    // Error occurred while updating the book
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to update book' });
  }
};


// Get the book cover image

const getBookCover = async (req, res) => {

};

 module.exports = {
   saveBook,
   getAllBooks,
   editBookById,
   uploadImage,
   getBookCover
 };
```

this is the code for the reducer

```
const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    books: [],
    error: '',
    fileURL: '' // Add the fileURL property to the initial state
  };


const booksReducers = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    // Fetch books reducers
    
    case 'FETCH_BOOKS_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    
    case 'FETCH_BOOKS_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, loading: false, books: action.payload, error: '' };
    
    case 'FETCH_BOOKS_FAILURE':
      return { ...state, loading: false, books: [], error: action.payload };

    // Edit book reducers
    
    case 'EDIT_BOOK_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loading: true };

    case 'EDIT_BOOK_SUCCESS':
      const editedBook = action.payload;
      const updatedBooks = state.books.map((book) =>
      book._id === editedBook._id ? editedBook : book
      );
      return { ...state, loading: false, books: updatedBooks };
    
    case 'EDIT_BOOK_FAILURE':
        return { ...state, error: action.payload, loading: false };

    // Upload image reducers

    case 'UPLOAD_IMAGE_REQUEST':
      return { ...state, loading: true };

    case 'UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS':
      return { ...state, loading: false, fileURL: action.payload, error: "" };

    case 'UPLOAD_IMAGE_FAILURE':
      return { ...state, error: action.payload, loading: false };
      


    default:
      return state;
  }
};
  
  export default booksReducers;
```

this is the code for the entire component just incase the info can help

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { editBook, uploadImage } from '../actions/booksActions';

const BookDetails = ({ book }) => {
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const [editedTitle, setEditedTitle] = useState(book.title);
  const [editedAuthor, setEditedAuthor] = useState(book.author);
  const [editedDescription, setEditedDescription] = useState(book.description);
  const [isSaving, setIsSaving] = useState(false); // Added state for saving/loading
  const [error, setError] = useState(null); // Added state for error handling
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const fileURL = useSelector((state) => state.fileURL);

  const handleEditClick = () => {
    setIsEditing(true);
  };

  const handleSaveClick = async () => {
    try {
      setIsSaving(true); // Set saving state to true
  
      const editedBook = {
        ...book,
        title: editedTitle,
        author: editedAuthor,
        description: editedDescription,
      };
  
      if (selectedImage) {
        console.log("what the fuck");
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('bookCover', selectedImage);
        try {
          const response = await dispatch(uploadImage(formData));
          console.log("is this even being checked");
          console.log(response);
          editedBook.bookCover = response.payload.fileURL;
  
          // Rest of your code that depends on the response goes here
          await dispatch(editBook(book._id, editedBook));
  
          setIsEditing(false);
          setIsSaving(false);
          setError(null);
          setEditedTitle(book.title); // Reset edited values
          setEditedAuthor(book.author);
          setEditedDescription(book.description);
        } catch (uploadError) {
          console.log(uploadError);
          setError('Failed to upload image. Please try again.');
        }
      } else {
        // Rest of your code when selectedImage is not present goes here
        await dispatch(editBook(book._id, editedBook));
  
        setIsEditing(false);
        setIsSaving(false);
        setError(null);
        setEditedTitle(book.title); // Reset edited values
        setEditedAuthor(book.author);
        setEditedDescription(book.description);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setIsSaving(false);
      setError('Failed to save changes. Please try again.');
    }
  };
  

  const handleImageChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    setSelectedImage(file);
  };

  return (
    <div className="book-details">
      <img src={book.bookCover} alt={book.title} />
      {isEditing ? (
        <>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={editedTitle}
            onChange={(e) => setEditedTitle(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            value={editedAuthor}
            onChange={(e) => setEditedAuthor(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            value={editedDescription}
            onChange={(e) => setEditedDescription(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={handleImageChange} />
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <h3>{book.title}</h3>
          <p>{book.author}</p>
          <p>{book.description}</p>
        </>
      )}
      {isEditing ? (
        <>
          {isSaving ? (
            <button className="save-btn" disabled>
              Saving...
            </button>
          ) : (
            <button className="save-btn" onClick={handleSaveClick}>
              Save
            </button>
          )}
        </>
      ) : (
        <button className="edit-btn" onClick={handleEditClick}>
          Edit
        </button>
      )}
      <button className="delete-btn">Delete</button>
      {error && <p className="error">{error}</p>}
      {/* Add more book details as needed */}
    </div>
  );
};


export default BookDetails;
```

at first i tried using ta loop to loop until the response was given, i then tried await and async but i learned you cant await an action function i then lastly tried javascript promises. i am trying to get the code to wait for the response from the backend then continue with the other lines of code and eventually push the changes to the backend